# Simple redirect from public to views in ror

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking for a simple way to redirect the public/index.html to the app/views/public/index.html.erb the site is already deployed and I'm sick of it not being the first thing when you go to the domain.

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have public/index.html deleted and use rails routes instead.

Comment: I get an error "The page you were looking for doesn't exist." without the public/index.html

Comment: @ThomasReggi, in routes.rb you can specify your root, for instance (root :to => 'pages#main'). Rails Guides has a good section on routes (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).